# is there is way to use custom model in ml5 yolo()?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, tensorflow.js, yolo

since ml5 `yolo()` mention that

> "this implementation is heavily derived from ModelDepot".

It didn't mention which pre-train model it is using or how can you use your own trained model

```
let video;
let yolo;
let status;
let objects = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(320, 240);
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.size(320, 240);

  // Create a YOLO method
  yolo = ml5.YOLO(video, startDetecting);

  // Hide the original video
  video.hide();
  status = select('#status');
}

function draw() {
  image(video, 0, 0, width, height);
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    noStroke();
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    text(objects[i].className, objects[i].x * width, objects[i].y * height - 5);
    noFill();
    strokeWeight(4);
    stroke(0, 255, 0);
    rect(objects[i].x * width, objects[i].y * height, objects[i].w * width, objects[i].h * height);
  }
}

function startDetecting() {
  status.html('Model loaded!');
  detect();
}

function detect() {
  yolo.detect(function(err, results) {
    objects = results;
    detect();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code and problem. Could you specify your question?

Comment: @Archie I come across ml5 just while back, and I found it very easy to use, so I decide to use yolo as per there documentation and it works fine. but I want to use my own trained model. for example, it didn't detect Rubick cube and I want to use my own trained model which know what Rubick cube is.in other word I just want to use some other pre-trained model

Comment: due to some circumstance, I m forced to make  yolo model in javascript, which I m not that familiar like python

Comment: from my source, they didn't mention in the documentation, but I think they're using https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-data-and-models/tree/master/models/YOLO this pre-train model

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading yolo documentation and I kinda found a way:

ml5-yolo-library -> Heavily derived from https://github.com/ModelDepot/tfjs-yolo-tiny (ModelDepot: modeldepot.io)

here -> https://modeldepot.io/mikeshi/tiny-yolo-in-javascript

says -> This model was created from taking the original Darknet Tiny YOLO cfg and weights, converting it into Keras via YAD2K, and then using tensorflowjs_converter to convert it into the Tensorflow.js format.

So, i'm trying to do the same as you right now. hope i'll find a way